# Unmanaged 64-bit DLL copied to SysWOW64 and not System32 by Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, 32bit-64bit, unmanaged

I have a driver I have written in unmanaged C++ using Visual Studio 2010. When compiling the DLL on a 64-bit Windows 7 the post-build step is:

```
echo Copying $(TargetFileName) to the OS's 64-bit system folder ...
xcopy $(TargetPath) $(SystemRoot)\System32\. /Y /Q
```

However, the dll is copied to $(SystemRoot)\SysWOW64\ instead, which supposedly only happends to 32-bit assemblies.

BUT! If I copy the dll to System32 using Windows Explorer or with xcopy from a command shell the dll is correctly placed in the System32 folder. What am I doing wrong? Is it because Visual Studio is a 32-bit program and the POST-BUILD event is run in context of that 32-bit process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is being run from a 32-bit process.  As a sort of band-aid solution you should be able to replace `system32` with `sysnative` and the WOW64 layer should do the right thing.

**Update:** Sorry, maybe this instead: `%windir%\sysnative\cmd.exe /C "xcopy ..."`

Comment: Tried a xcopy now of the dll to c:\windows\sysnative\ but did not work, dll do not end up in either system32 nor SysWOW64.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen - Hm, I don't remember all the wrinkles of how the `sysnative` hack works.  See my update

Answer (score 0):

The variable SystemRoot is expanded corresponding to the calling program.

Since the calling program (devenv.exe) is a 32-Bit program it is replaced with the SysWOW64.

Comment: I placed "echo" in front of the xcopy now, and this was its output: xcopy C:\dev\test\Drivers\ODBC\trunk\src\Debug\odbc64.dll C:\Windows\System32\. /Y /Q

Comment: Indeed. Windows mimics for a 32-Bit program a directory C:\Windows\System32 that in reality points to the SysWOW64. Your "echo ..." confirmed this. You could start a 64 bit CMD.exe and pass the \Windows\System32 in a command string to reach the 64 bit System32 directory.

Comment: You are definitly on to something. If I run the xcopy from syswow64\cmd.exe (32-bit cmd.exe) the dll ends up in syswow64, and if I run the same xcopy from system32\cmd.exe (64-bit cmd.exe) the dll ends up in the system32 folder. A pattern has emerged.